# I need to add numbering format as Q.1 during designing the question paper, instead of format as 1. How to get it?

Tags: numbering, exam

I need to add numbering format as Q.1 during designing the question paper, instead of format as 1. How to get it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! One version: use `enumitem` and `enumerate` with the correct parameters. But without seeing *how* you are trying to achieve this (minimal code example needed), we cannot really help you.

Answer (score 2):

For instance, if there is only one level of questions:

```
.............
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist{questions}{label=Q.\arabic*., labelsep=2em, itemsep=0pt}
..........

\begin{document}
............
\begin{questions}
\item Explain briefly the steps in \emph{Agrobacterium} mediated gene transfer in plants.
\item ...
.............
\end{questions}
.............

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using the `exam` class and the `questions` environment as shown in the following MWE you can redefine `\thequestion` to print 'Q.1.' and so on.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{Q.\arabic{question}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question example question
\question another example question
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```